# Using typeof inside a Class

Tags: typescript

The question is **How/can we can use typeof to specify type of class property?** Check the both examples bellow, example A is working, example B inside class is not.

A) Working outside class

```
const data:{age:number, name:string} = {age:10, name:'John'};
const age:typeof data.age = 33;
```

B) Not working inside class. **How/Can we use same approach as in A inside s class?**

```
class Person{
    
    data: {age:number, name:string} = {age:10, name:'John'};
    age: typeof this.data.age; // Error, Cannot find name 'this'.(2304)

}
```

Comment: Use `Person` instead of `this`

Comment: @apokryfos Tnx for the fast reply but it does not work. you get 

class Person{
    
    data: {age:number, name:string} = {age:10, name:'John'};
    age: typeof Person.data.age;  //Property 'data' does not exist on type 'typeof Person'.

}

Comment: `age:  Person['data']['age']` should work. In this context `Person` already behaves as a type so does not need `typeof` you'd need `typeof` for instances of type `Person`

Comment: @apokryfos Tnx, this indead works !

class Person{
    
    data: {age:number, name:string} = {age:10, name:'John'};
    age: Person['data']['age'] = 12; 

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @apokryfos, in the comments this solutions works!

```
class Person {
    
    data: {age:number, name:string} = {age:10, name:'John'};
    age: Person['data']['age'] = 12; 

}
```